# characteristics of Kinect V2 Infrared images

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, infrared

I want to use Kinect v2 and record Depth, IR, and RGB images. About the characteristics of depth image we all know that depth image shows distance of person from the Kinect sensor and as we move close or far from the sensor the depth values changes. However, I want to know about the characteristics of IR image. If the person is standing in front of sensor and after some time he forward does the IR image show any change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IR image is simply the intensity of reflected IR radiation as emitted by the Kinect. The IR image will not show any change in distance other than the illumination tapering off if you move too far away and the sensor saturating if you have are too close or have a reflective surface in front of the Kinect.

Comment: Konsalik: it means we can say that IR image is intensity based imaged image?

Comment: @FrqKhan Yes, you could say that

Comment: Does the intensity of RGB image changes with the changes of light? whereas the intensity of IR is not dependent on the light, correct?

Comment: The RGB sensor is passive and makes use of ambient light. The IR is active and the Kinect projects it's own light source. Therefore you can make the room pitch black (no image on colour) but still see the IR image.